# Retornar valor baseado em critério de data dentro de range de data inicial e final e ID em outro data frame? (pandas e python)

Tags: python, pandas

Possuo dois `dataframes`, aonde o `df1` contém a coluna `Data` e `Praca_ID`, aonde preciso procurar no `df2`, que possui `DataInicial` `DataFinal` `Praca_ID` e `Tarifa` (coluna a ser retornada.)

O exemplo do jupyterlab no [meu github](https://github.com/m4rc10jr/sag-pracas-etl/blob/master/etl.ipynb) vai detalhar bem o problema:

Repare a linha In [46]: que faz o código:

```
# Procurando tarifa equivalente ao tráfego da data a ser analisada:

dfTrafegoPracas['Tarifa'] = np.where((dfTarifas.Praca == dfTrafegoPracas.Praca) 
& (dfTarifas.VigenciaInicial<=dfTrafegoPracas.Data) & 
(dfTarifas.VigenciaFinal>=dfTrafegoPracas.Data), dfTarifas['Tarifa'], '')
```

Eu comentei esta etapa porque não consigo fazer funcionar..

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!

O merge tambem funcionou, mas era ineficiente em quesitos de desempenho e processamento.

Instalei e importei o pandassql,fiz as 2 linhas abaixo:

```
 sqlcode = '''
select dfTrafegoPracas.Data,
dfTrafegoPracas.Praca,
dfTrafegoPracas.Sentido,
dfTrafegoPracas.Pista,
dfTrafegoPracas.Categoria,
dfTrafegoPracas.Perfil,
dfTrafegoPracas.Trafego,
dfTrafegoPracas.Multiplicador,
dfTrafegoPracas.Eixos,
dfTrafegoPracas.InitialPath,
dfTarifas.Tarifa
from dfTrafegoPracas
inner join dfTarifas on dfTrafegoPracas.Praca=dfTarifas.Praca
where dfTrafegoPracas.Data >= dfTarifas.VigenciaInicial and dfTrafegoPracas.Data <= dfTarifas.VigenciaFinal
'''


dfTrafegoPracas = ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```